# Does IO multiplexing on one single read-only fd help get better performance than simply blocking read on it?

Tags: c, sockets, io, asyncsocket, multiplexing

According to my knowledge, I think if I only need to perform reading operation on one single fd, IO multiplexing like select/poll will not help on performance, it even causes more overhead than just reading fd blockingly.

But the [linux auditd project](https://fedorahosted.org/audit/browser/trunk/src/auditd.c#L925) however use select on one single reading socket.  Could someone explain what the meaning of it?

The auditd code alse use libev on 1 socket/ 1 pipe and 5 signals. Is it better to use blocking read if I only care about the main netlink socket?

I think possible scenarios may be a listening udp receiver socket etc.

Code block is attached for convenience. Thanks in advance!

```
925 static int get_reply(int fd, struct audit_reply *rep, int seq)
926 {
927         int rc, i;
928         int timeout = 30; /* tenths of seconds */
929 
930         for (i = 0; i < timeout; i++) {
931                 struct timeval t;
932                 fd_set read_mask;
933 
934                 t.tv_sec  = 0;
935                 t.tv_usec = 100000; /* .1 second */
936                 FD_ZERO(&read_mask);
937                 FD_SET(fd, &read_mask);
938                 do {
939                         rc = select(fd+1, &read_mask, NULL, NULL, &t);
940                 } while (rc < 0 && errno == EINTR);
941                 rc = audit_get_reply(fd, rep, 
942                         GET_REPLY_NONBLOCKING, 0);
943                 if (rc > 0) {
944                         /* Don't make decisions based on wrong packet */
945                         if (rep->nlh->nlmsg_seq != seq)
946                                 continue;
947 
948                         /* If its not what we are expecting, keep looping */
949                         if (rep->type == AUDIT_SIGNAL_INFO)
950                                 return 1;
951 
952                         /* If we get done or error, break out */
953                         if (rep->type == NLMSG_DONE || rep->type == NLMSG_ERROR)
954                                 break;
955                 }
956         }
957         return -1;
958 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance would likely be variable depending on the platform (in this case Linux) but it shouldn't be quicker.

It seems the main reason the code is using `select` is for its timeout abilities. It allows a read-with-timeout without actually modifying the timeout (`SO_SNDTIMEO`, `SO_RCVTIMEO`) of the socket [or if the socket at all even supports timeouts].

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not get better performance by using an I/O multiplexing system like `select()` or `poll()` to listen for data on a single socket, compared with continuous blocking reads on that socket.